# Electron NSIS silent uninstaller does not delete the app folder if the app is running

Tags: electron, nsis, uninstallation

We build an electron app which uses electron-builder to make a NSIS installer. Everything works fine except when the uninstaller is run in silent mode and the app is still running. The observed issue is that the app is not terminated (as expected), and the installation is only partially removed.

The electron-builder version is 19.48.3, which has a hardcoded dependency on nsis 3.0.1.13, and nsis-resources 3.3.0.

The documentation says the uninstaller has to be run with an /S option, and any MessageBoxes has to have a /SD option to designate a silent result, which is the case with the app.

Is there anything else I am missing which controls the behavior in this use case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with the one click installers. To overcome that I made nsis configurations like [this](https://github.com/zulip/zulip-electron/blob/f70432f4e3cdc86ae610bf3d77bfa2e784fabdf3/package.json#L102). You can give it a try, and see if that works out for you.

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) — “Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline”